# Loop back to the top?

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to make the wrong entry in address to repeat the question 'Where do you live?' using the while method but it doesn't seem to work any more.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ImScrewed {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean flag = true;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (flag) {
            System.out.println("== Welcome to UwU Cafe! ==");
            System.out.print("What is your name? [Starts with 'Mr. ' or 'Ms. '] : ");
            String name = scan.nextLine();

            if (name.startsWith("Ms. ") || name.startsWith("Mr. ")) {
                System.out.println("Welcome : " + name);
                flag = false;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please re-enter your name");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Where do you live? [Contains 'Street']");
        String address = scan.nextLine();

        if (address.contains("Street")) {
            System.out.println("Proceed to the next step");
            flag = false;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please re-enter your address");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "loop back to the top" - you don't have anything like a loop - you should probably have a look at a `while` loop.

Comment: in addition, the name of your class should start with a capital letter. "ImScrewed"

Comment: You will need another while loop for the `street`.

Comment: I did but it said syntax error and I had to delete it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop back in case of error. With the help of a boolean variable and a  simple while loop it should be just fine.

Something like this:

```
boolean flag = true;

do {
    String name = scan.nextLine();
    if (name.startsWith("Ms. ") || name.startsWith("Mr. ")) {
        System.out.println("Welcome : " + name);
        // break the loop.
        flag = false;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please re-enter your name");
    } 
} while (flag);
```

You can also eliminate the variable. By doing something like:

```
while (true) {
    String name = scan.nextLine();
    if (name.startsWith("Ms. ") || name.startsWith("Mr. ")) {
        System.out.println("Welcome : " + name);
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please re-enter your name");
    }
}
```

EDIT: support or multiple fields.

```
// previous while loop here

flag = true; // resetting flag

while (flag) {
    System.out.println("Where do you live? [Contains 'Street']");
    String address = scan.nextLine();

    if (address.contains("Street")) {
        System.out.println("Proceed to the next step");
        // terminate the loop
        flag = false;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please re-enter your address");
    }
}
```

Comment: @HarshalParekh, `flag = false` is not how you `break` a loop.

Comment: Please try the code. It will break the loop. You don't always need `break` to terminate a loop.

Comment: My point is that any statement after `flag = false` will still get executed and using a  `break` eliminates that possibility.

Comment: In this scenario, that is the last line. I have taken your feedback into consideration and edited the answer.

Comment: The while (flag) in the do-while loop has to be after the last curly brace and not after the else block.

Comment: @ShubhamSaraswat, nice catch. Maybe it got there because multiple people are editing here very quickly. I have fixed it.

Comment: Umm, I wanna ask what if I want to insert another loop? The 'while' doesn't seem to work anymore

Comment: Please undelete it :") I very much need it, thankyou!

Comment: I'm sorry but I copied your codes and tried to run it but nothing came up on the console.

Comment: Did you reset the `flag` variable to `true`?

Comment: I'm sorry, it was my mistake. I didn't check it thoroughly. Thank you very much! I'm a bit more confident for my quiz now :")